# Copy-pasting Docked Control in C# Designer

Tags: c#, designer, tablelayoutpanel

I am designing the UI of my program with a TableLayoutPanel, with each control docked in its cell with `Dock = Fill`. Since a lot of the controls are similar, I want to use copy-paste to populate the layout. However, the newly pasted control is put in the *bottom*-left cell by default. Furthermore, since it is docked, I cannot move it in the designer, so the only way I could put it in the correct cell is by setting `Dock = None`, drag it, then setting `Dock = Fill` again. This is very annoying, and to some extent defeats the purpose to use copy-paste in the first place (to avoid forgetting to set `Dock`). Are there any better ways I can create such a layout?

Comment: Your complaint should be filed at Microsoft, we don't get to change the way the designer works.  A simple workaround is to do this in the correct order.  Don't dock the control right away.  First copy-paste the controls, then Shift+Click select them and set their Dock property.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't think of Shift+Click to multiselect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that, when put into a TableLayoutPanel, the control has a `Cell` property. Modifying it allows me to move the control within the TableLayoutPanel without first undocking it.

Of course, Hans Passant's suggestion of first moving the controls, then mass-set the `Dock` property also works.